# OKTA User Impersonation _Masquerade

Tags: okta, impersonation, okta-api, masquerade

This in context with OKTA. I am logged in as a Superuser (Admin) and trying to perform user impersonation via switch or masquerading in OKTA but could not locate the option in the user profile or anywhere else. How can we achieve it?

The ultimate aim is to fetch the token for a specific user. So that On his behalf I can access the API, test, or debug without ogin into the application for that user or using the password.

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible to do in Okta. The only way to obtain a token as a user is to login as the user

Comment: Thanks, Philipp. Do we have any documentation or any link which confirms this?

Comment: I don't believe it's mentioned anywhere explicitly.

Comment: Okay, thank you. We can close this.